# JRE 8, TDM-GCC MinGW: Instalação silenciosa

Tags: batch

Alguém sabe como instalar silenciosamente o JRE 8 ( jre-8u65-windows-i586 ) por meio de um arquivo bat ?

E se possível também poderiam me informar como instalar o TDM-GCC ( MiNGW32) do mesmo jeito ?

Para esses dois já tentei em um arquivo bat :

"nome do programa.exe" /S
Ou 
"nome do programa.exe" /SILENT

mas não deu certo

A+

Comment: Só espero que não seja em máquina de terceiros. O último programa aqui que tentou "infectar" minha máquina com JRE sem avisar, além de ser "banido" do meu PC, rendeu um email mal educado pro fornecedor.

Answer (score 3):

De acordo com a [documentação da Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/windows_installer_options.html),

> [...] you may use the option /s for the JRE Windows Offline Installer to perform a silent installation.

O exemplo provido é o seguinte:

```
jre-8-windows-i586.exe /s
```

(Perceba que argumentos de *command line* podem ser *case-sensitive*. Teste `/s` ao invés de `/S`.)

Quanto ao TDM-GCC MinGW Compiler, [não há no momento opções de instalação não-interativa](https://sourceforge.net/p/tdm-gcc/feature-requests/33/).

Comment: É  isso mesmo  lbotinelly , Acho que era só o case-sensitive mesmo. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @Rulho fico feliz que tenha funcionado!